# I am trying to analyze below query related to hierarchical and Regex can any one help me in understanding?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchical, listagg, regexp-substr

I have come across below query, but I am not able to conclude my analysis related to below query. The main aim of the below query is to convert the number to the alphabet. But the usage of the hierarchical query made me confuse.

```
merge into s_export ex
using (
       select
        listagg(n, '') within group (order by lv) new_val,
        row_id
      from
        (
          SELECT
            connect_by_root rowid row_id,
            LEVEL lv,
            CASE
               WHEN Regexp_like(Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL ), '\d+')
                  THEN spell_number(
                                Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2),
                                Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 3)
                               )
               ELSE Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL )
            END N
          FROM s_export d
          CONNECT BY NOCYCLE Regexp_substr( file_as, '([^0-9]+)|(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?', 1, LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL
                             and rowid = prior rowid
                             and prior dbms_random.value is not null
        )
      group by row_id
                      ) t
on (t.row_id = ex.rowid)
when matched then
 update set ex.file_as = t.new_val;
```

Sample Dataset:

```
create table s_export  (file_as varchar2(2000));


insert into s_export  values ('Collection Four') ;
insert into s_export  values ('OM_Forty-One One');
insert into s_export  values ('OM_Twenty-Two | SOFifteen');
insert into s_export  values ('1st');
insert into s_export  values ('3M');
insert into s_export  values ('Collection Six');
insert into s_export  values ('2ND');
insert into s_export  values ('11TH100');
```

Below is my understanding so far:

1. We are performing an update on the table `s_export` column
   `file_as` whenever there is any number say `1`, it will convert this
   to `'one'`.
2. As far as `LEVEL` used in `Regexp_substr` work as an occurrence.

Comment: take some sample data from table `s_export` then you can use a service like https://sqlfiddle.com https://dbfiddle.uk/  https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler to set-up a select query (not the update) and study the result. If you still have trouble paste the URL to the example so we can help. No sample data = not much we can do

Comment: @Used_By_Already sample data updated,

Comment: Yes, I see the sample data but I don't have the function spell_number(). I suggest you just run part of that query from `select ... to ... group by row_id` and inspect that result

Comment: see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5055d66bd12ece85ee6a2a7c641c0d6e

Comment: Yes, I have executed, but unfortunately, the function did not work.

Comment: Sure I will try to inspect, actually I wanted to know usage of higherarical queries here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed the query mentioned above, Below is my analysis for reference.

Consider we have sample data in our table **s_export**, our Aim here is to **convert numeric value appeared in a string into the alphabet**.

```
file_as     ROW_ID
-------     -------
123Test123  101
```

**We can divide the query into 3 parts starting from the innermost**

### Step 1: Transform the string into the alphabet.

```
   SELECT
        connect_by_root rowid row_id,
        LEVEL lv,
        CASE
           WHEN Regexp_like(Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL ), '\d+')
              THEN spell_number(
                            Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2),
                            Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 3)
                           )
           ELSE Regexp_substr( file_as, '[^0-9]+|((\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?)', 1, LEVEL )
        END N
      FROM s_export d
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE Regexp_substr( file_as, '([^0-9]+)|(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)?', 1, LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL
                         and rowid = prior rowid
                         and prior dbms_random.value is not null
```

If there is any string in **file_as** column say in our case "123Test123", this query will take row_id of the particular row and get the substring from them eg consider row_id of this string as 101 now there will be 3 rows with the same row_id the only difference will be no of the level(No of splits) and every numeric will be converted into the alphabet, using (spell_number)

Original value : 123Test123

```
ROW_ID  LV      N
------- ------- -------
101     1       One Hundred Twenty-Three
101     2       Test
101     3       One Hundred Twenty-Three
```

### 2: Grouping the data achieved from the transformation

```
 select
    listagg(n, '') within group (order by lv) new_val,
    row_id
  from (
  ---Query from Step 1
  )  group by row_id
```

Now with the result acheaved from the above output we will perform "listagg" (like pivot the column to row) and concatinate the values of column  "N", acheaved from the inner most query to obtain single string value on the basis of grouping them
with respect to row_id,

```
NEW_VAL                                                     ROW_ID
-------                                                     -------
One Hundred Twenty-Three Test One Hundred Twenty-Three      101
```

### Step 3: Merge the data into the column of the original table

```
merge into s_export ex
using (
        --Query from Step 2 (Including Step 1)
        )  t
on (t.row_id = ex.rowid)
when matched then
 update set ex.file_as = t.new_val;
```

Now, we will merge "NEW_VAL", obtained from above query to "file_as" column of s_export, on the basis of row_id.

Final Transformed result :

```
file_as                                                     ROW_ID
-------                                                     -------
One Hundred Twenty-Three Test One Hundred Twenty-Three      101
```